# $.ajax post function security

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking into security for my webapp. I currently log in my user using an ajax post to a php file.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login_StartUserSession.php",
        data: ({usr: theUser, pwd: thePassword}),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success:  function(data){.....}
```

I'd like to know how this data is passed to the server. Is it just in plain text by default? Is this a possible security issue? Am I able to encrypt the password without using HTTPS?

Comment: I think this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269598/ajax-login-password-encryption

Comment: It's no more a security issue than a regular request with a form, it's the exact same thing, and yes, the username and password is sent in plain text

Comment: I tought that every page was html as a default so you need to set contenttype to text/plain. I don't know if you already do so but you might also wanna check if your users have javascript turned on before doing anything else

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know how this data is passed to the server.

It's posted with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, and the transferred data looks like `usr=test&pwd=test`.

> Is this a possible security issue?

Only if the URL you're sending the data to is HTTP. You'll want HTTPS for anything sensitive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you know is there a way to encrypt the password without https?

Comment: @Janey There is no secure way of doing so, because an attacker could serve your users malicious JavaScript code that erases your protection. HTTPS is now free with stuff like https://letsencrypt.org/ - there's **no excuse** for not using it for sensitive data like usernames/passwords.

Comment: The real question is, do you *need* to encrypt the password? Does your site store credit card info, personal info etc. or are you running a bank? If it's just a regular login, say with an email and password, to a site similar to Stack Overflow etc. that doesn't store anything of value, do you really need SSL and encrypted passwords? I agree that SSL is free/cheap, and should generally be used, but most sites don't use SSL, and they really don't need it either.

Comment: It's actually far more important to ***never*** store passwords on the server, and have a proper hashing and salting system in place

Comment: @adeneo yes the database stores sensitive information :/

Comment: @Janey Then you must use HTTPS.